# how to access folder of css files in magento

Tags: css, magento

I am very new to magento. I am really confused how to load my own CSS files into magento. From some internet help, I came to know that, we have to save these CSS files at some location similar to

```
var/www/company_name/skin/frontend/default/magento_new_theme/css/folder
```

I also read that during installation of magento, we create all these folders or they are created automatically. (Please correct me, if wrong).

The thing is , I have no magento installed. I am accessing the magento system from website of my company. And I really want some help regarding, where, I have to go to get this `var` folder?

Note : It is magento but not magento go.

Answer (score 2):

For using css from current theme you can use the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/newstyle.css') >" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To add your own CSS files, navigate to your local xml file. It will be at `app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/local.xml`

If it does not exist, make a copy from the default folder into the same location in your theme's folders. Open it up and inside the section `<reference name="head">` include the below

```
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/Custom_file1.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/Custom_file2.css</name><params/></action>
```

Provided these CSS files exist in your `skin/frontend/package/theme/css` folder then they will be added to the document's head.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
<?php
 $this->getSkinUrl('css/name.css');
 ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you  have using `default` skin  `package` and skin template `magento_new_theme` then,then you can use

```
Mage::getSkinUrl('css/folder'); //for folder
```

Css file

```
Mage::getSkinUrl('css/folder/yourcssfile.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Magento installation is at the root URI of your website, the path for CSS is "/skin/frontend/package/theme/css" and for images "/skin/frontend/package/theme/images", typically.

The 'package' and 'theme' names will be set in your Magento admin. The default package is 'base' and the theme is 'default', so that path would be "/skin/frontend/base/default/".

You will need to ask your Magento admin what the package and theme names are.

Comment: I really apologize, but I am confused. Can you please tell me where is this where to go inside Magento, to reach this skin folder?